# Display External Data in Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I'm using Kentico CMS 7 and there is a way to import external data from Database

http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?displaying_data_from_external_database.htm

Displaying data from an external database kentico need to be included in visual studio 
so i can customize it
but there is something missing in this article of how to include webproject.sln with some pages already made in kentico based on virtual paths like (Home.aspx - Conatct.aspx - About.aspx) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean import the data, then I suggest to use Kentico Import Toolkit.
If you just want to display data from external database, then it depends on what your development model in Kentico CMS is.

1. Portal engine mode - mentioning the virtual paths for pages like Home.aspx suggests that you use portal engine development. In that case you don't need to write your own code. Use the **SQL data source** webpart with combination of a viewer webpart like repeater. You can also develop your own webpart to do what you want, see the documentation [of how to create a webpart](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?web_parts_api_examples_managing_web_parts.htm).
2. ASPX development mode - this mode allows you to leverage your existing knowledge of ASP.NET and write standard code in similar way how it is described in the article.

In situation you would truly need to edit portal engine templates in Visual Studio you need to  deploy it from DB to file system. See this [article](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?team_development_deployment_and_source.htm).

Comment: Lately i've been confirmed that------ the external database on this task MySqlDB need  to be  viewed , so any advises about how to (just view / Update) this data.
should i convert it into XML or convert it to SQLServer and what about to view it?